# wxPython: How to refresh and draw on wx.Frame from an unrelated class

Tags: python

I have two classes in an application and the first is a wx class, which is instantiated as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    ExampleFrame(None, 'Does Nothing')
    NewX = X(sys.argv)
    app.MainLoop()
```

The class itself looks like the following:

```
class ExampleFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(ExampleFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=ttl, size=(600, 600))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def DrawLine(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    def Clear():
        self.Hide
        self.Show
        # NOW DRAW SOME LINES....
```

The other Class instance is say, Class X, where I try to call ExampleFrame.Clear(), but it fails.

My question is, How do I call the Clear() method in ExampleFrame from Class X? What am I missing?

EDIT: When the python script fails, it does throw some sort of error, but the window closes too quickly to see what it states.

Comment: Can you be more precise with "it fails" ? Does is crash, raise some kind of exception or error(if so what is it) or simply doesnt have any effect?

Comment: Well aren't you starting your application from terminal? The error should be logged there.

Comment: Ah, don't I feel like an idiot right now. I was running the script right out of IDLE. It never occurred to me to run it from the command line. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign references of wx objects to variables and at that point you can access their functions like any other object:

```
ef = ExampleFrame(None, 'Something')
NewX = X(sys.argv, ef)
```

Now from within X, you'd need to store this reference so other methods can access it:

```
def __init__(self, argv, ef):
   # Some other stuff
   self.__ef = ef
```

Methods of X now have access to your frame:

```
# X method
def clearFrameFromX(self):
   self.__ef.Clear()
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the passing of references. I think I've got a better understanding of object orientation now. I come from a procedural programming background, and OO principles are seriously confounding.